# Can inherited arity be overriden?

Tags: uml

I have this class/object diagram:

[image]

I don’t understand why that  object diagram is invalid according to the given class diagram.

In the object diagram, one C object has two links with two T objects, alpha relationship with a T object and beta relationship with another T. So I don’t think it violates the multiplicity constraints.

Could you please explain me why the object diagram is invalid?

Comment: What is the class diagram? What is arity of that relation in the class diagram?

Comment: sorry for my mistake. Now The diagram was left to upload because of the poor connection here. Now I have uploaded that. Is it ok just showing the link or I have to show it explicitly?

Comment: This is a great question that is tripping up even experienced UML folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is the most interesting question I've seen here in a long time. It is pretty tricky!

The simple reason your instances are incorrect is that every instance of type `T` must be associated with one `C`. The top instance of type `T` in your diagram violates the constraint in association `beta`. (The multiplicity on the left end of the association.)

Comment: No. Both instances are wrong. Each `T` has two associations. One to `C` and one to `A` (inherited from `S`). If you add association end names, the picture would be much clearer. (I don't know if there is something like association inheritance in UML.)

Comment: I don't think you can make it to the mults. They are two different associations. If they had assoc.-end names it would be clear.

Comment: Yes, that is the solution. However, he asked why the current diagram is incorrect. I kept it very simple on purpose. (All constraints for `C` are actually met as it stands!)

Comment: Yes, there is association inheritance in UML. Many flavors, in fact.

Comment: Yes, association ends would help.

Comment: I still think that `C` needs two associations to `T`. Without end-names it's a bit pointless and lets room for speculation. So actually the answer is likely: your class diagram is incomplete. Hence your OD can not be told wrong or right.

Comment: I agree that it needs two associations, but the OP asked us to explain the _invalidity_!

Answer (score 0):

Leaving my prior answer below, but thinking twice, the answer is that your class diagram is incomplete.

The two alpha and beta associations have no association-end names. The fact that they have different multiplicities leads to the conclusion that they must be different associations. With names it would look like this:

[image]

Expanding the inheritance will make this:

[image]

Based on this assumption, my original answer stands like this:

The reason is that a `:C` has two associations alpha and beta each to another `:T` object. Not a single alpha to one and a single beta to another. So you need to add a beta to the alpha and vice versa.

**Edit** And yes, JimL. is correct. Having two alpha-links violates the constraint from the class diagram. So actually you can only have one `T` linked to `C`. Which again makes the class model very strange.

[image]

The `C` class has a beta-association to `T`. `C` inherits from `A` and `T` inherits from `S`. Since there is a alpha-association from `A` t0 `S` this is also inherited. So you have:

[image]

Comment: Whenever there is alpha relationship, there is also beta relationship?
I may link :C with t1:T with only alpha relationship and may link :C with t2:T with beta relationship. 
Is it not possible?
Suppose A is student and C is master student. S is book and T is thesis book.
Alpha is “read” association and beta is “borrow”.
Every student can read one book in the library.
But only master student can borrow thesis book.
Is it not possible that a master student read one book and borrows another thesis book?
I am sorry if my question is a stupid one. But I still don’t get it.

Comment: The third picture (and corresponding information) is incorrect, as each A and thus each C object have to has exactly one alpha link, it would  be correct if you remove one of them.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, if you remove one of the alpha links from the third picture, it is correct. According to the class diagram, not every :T needs to be linked to a subclass of :A (multiplicity is *). By the way, association end names are not mandatory in a class diagram.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Yes, you are right. See my Edit note above the picture. Anyway I think the issue is not with the object representation but with the crude class structure itself. Maybe if one would know a concrete use of it... And: T must have two links alpha and beta!

Comment: Here's a concrete model for you: Substitute `Attendee` for `A`, `Meeting` for `S`, `Chairperson` for `C`, and `Chaired Meeting` for `T`. You'll end up with an instance of a `Chaired Meeting` having many instances of `Attendee`, some of whom are `Chairpersons`, as well as exactly one `Chairperson` who actually chairs the meeting.

Comment: @JimL. That indeed makes sense. Thanks :-) So in my OD one needs to remove one `:T` and add many `:S` with just an alpha-link to make it a correct picture.

Answer (score 0):

There are two faults in the object diagram.

There is only a formal fault in the object diagram, the lines in the objects diagrams between the instances are **links**, i.e., instances of the **associations** shown in the class diagram. As the links are instances, the same rules for instance naming apply as to class instances. So change **alpha** to **:alpha** and underline it, it is correct. Same for beta.

Further the links are not correct, as there is an beta link from the uppermost T instance missing. Each object of A, and as C is a specialization of A, also C (and B) objects need an **alpha** link to an S instance. As S is a generalized T, an alpha link between A (or one of its specializations) and S (or one of its specializations) is needed. Further each S (or T) might have arbitrary alpha links to A objects.
Each C object needs to have zero or one beta links to T instances. In the other direction, each T instance needs exactly one C instance via a beta link. This is missing for the uppermost T instance.

Comment: In §9.8.4 (Notation), the UML 2.5 spec says, "It is **not** necessary to show an underlined name where it is clear from its connection to instance specifications that it represents a link and not an Association." (Emphasis mine.) Thus, it is untrue that "the same rules for instance naming apply as to class instances."

Comment: Thanks, Jim, I was not aware of this, seems that this changed in one of the latest versions, maybe as many people and tools already handled it that way over years. But still there is a beta connection from the first T instance required.